# Returning value to a Fragment from a custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragments

From a Fragment i invoke a dialog

```
private void showDateDialog(){

         FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerDialogFragment((Fragment)this,localCalendar);
            newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
    }
```

Then in the custom dialog i call a timesetlistener

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_dialog, null);

            timePicker=(TimePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
            timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
            if (data!=null) {
                timePicker.setCurrentHour(data.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                timePicker.setCurrentMinute(data.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
          }
            timePicker.setScaleX(2);
            timePicker.setScaleY(2);

            return new TimePickerDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(R.string.timeDialog1)
            .setView(v)

            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //validation code
                    OnTimeSetListener otsl=(OnTimeSetListener)mFragment;
                    otsl.onTimeSet(timePicker, timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute()); 
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.annulla, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).create();
    }
```

and in the fragment i implement an OnTimeSetListener to get the values

```
 public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
            localCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            localCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            updateTime(hour,minute);
    }
```

and this is working fine. BUT i would like another custom dialog to return a string, and i don't know which listener to implement. I tried "onDismiss" but i can't pass parameters, i tried OnValueChangeListener but as parameters has 2 integers (i need a string!).
Is this the right way? I mean, to use listeners.

The good thing is that from any fragment that implements onDateChange i can launch the dialog and retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i answer by myself: i cannot figure out how to do it so i used this solution:
i build a different class for each dialog that parse the calling fragment and call a method in it. It's not the best solution but it's working